# Execute SQL query when/if X

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following INSERT:

```
        $id = \DB::table('log')
      ->insert(array(
        "account_id" => $this->get("account_id"),
        "type" => "Edit info",
        "done" => "0"
      ));
```

How could I adapt it in order to be executed **only** when there are no previous entries like this inside **log** table?

**account_id:** 1 // 
**type:** Edit info //
**done:** 0

I need to avoid repeating entries (no same entries if the user already requested edit his/her info and it wasn't **done** by an admin yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `updateOrInsert` method.

```
$id = \DB::table('log')->updateOrInsert(array(
  "account_id" => $this->get("account_id"),
  "type" => "Edit info",
  "done" => "0"
));
```

Comment: Thanks, Vitaliy. I tried with this before, but if I have previous changes requested who aren't related with "Edit info" type, they get replaced. That would work, but I need it to be executed only with "Edit info" type and "done = 0".

Comment: The `updateOrInsert` method takes 2 args. The first is array with attributes to search and the second with values to set. The result array is merged by those two arrays.

Comment: Is there a documentation for updateOrInsert? @VitaliyKrushelnitsky

Comment: https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_updateOrInsert You are welcome